# SSL handshake error

Tags: perl, ssl, https, openssl

I am hitting a handshake problem with one of our servers. I cant seem to figure out how to resolve this. A few days back, I was facing a similar issue while connecting to one of our other servers and you can follow that in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39746541/netldaps-throws-unknown-error-during-ssl-connect/) question. That issue was resolved but I am facing one more similar issue like that.

This is from the error logs.

```
DEBUG: .../IO/Socket/SSL.pm:415: connection failed - connect returned 0
DEBUG: .../IO/Socket/SSL.pm:1175: SSL connect attempt failed because of handshake problemserror:14094410:SSL routines:SSL3_READ_BYTES:sslv3 alert handshake failure
```

I ran an openssl command too and here is the output.

```
-> openssl s_client -connect ABC:443 -CApath XXX
CONNECTED(00000003)
...
31507:error:14094410:SSL routines:SSL3_READ_BYTES:sslv3 alert handshake failure:s3_pkt.c:1101:SSL alert number 40
31507:error:140790E5:SSL routines:SSL23_WRITE:ssl handshake failure:s23_lib.c:188:
```

I am seeing an alert number 40 there. Does it signify something?? 
Is the server expecting some sort of client certificates for the handshake?

Comment: `SSL alert number 40` means that the server won't accept the connection because no user certificate was presented. You have to specify the user certificate and the private key with the -cert and -key parameters. Try `openssl s_client -port 443 -CApath /usr/share/ssl/certs/ -host $host -prexit -cert your.client.certificate.cert -key your.private.key.key`

Comment: @ChankeyPathak: alert number 40 is a generic handshake failure which can be anything including missing client certificate. See [RFC5246 (TLS 1.2) section A.3 Alert Messages](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc5246#appendix-A.3).

Comment: Please add more debug information, i.e. output from `openssl s_client -debug ..`, packet capture of the handshake (as pcap) or similar. The current information are not enough since alert number 40 is just a generic handshake error.

Comment: @ChankeyPathak Passing the client cert and key seemed to work. I didnt see that error and at the end of the debug messages the openssl was waiting for my inputs. (I saw the same behavior when I ran the openssl s_client against other working sites).

Comment: The openssl worked but my script is still failing with the same error. More debugging for me. :(  Anyways, thank you folks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Coming to why it was specifically failing in my script, I found the reason for it.

Before answering that I will enlist my environment to have a context

> 1. Perl : 5.10.1 (custom perl managed by perlbrew). So I am not using the modules which come by default with the system perl.
> 2. Modules managed by cpanm
> 3. Running on Ubuntu 14.04

I resolved it by installing Crypt::SSLeay module. Apparently LWP module doesn't support https without this module.

I figured this out be enabling the debugging in IO::Socket::SSL module.

```
use IO::Socket qw(debug4);
```

It might help someone in the future :)

EDIT : My scripts are still failing for some SSL connections. Looks like the openssl version is the culprit according to the thread [here](http://www.perlmonks.org/?node_id=77123)

Comment: You may accept your own answer. See https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/01/accept-your-own-answers/

Answer (score 1):

You have to specify the user certificate and the private key with the `-cert` and `-key` parameters.

```
openssl s_client -port 443 -CApath /usr/share/ssl/certs/ -host $host -prexit -cert your.client.certificate.cert -key your.private.key.key
```